# Как задать высоту относительно flex родителя с flex-direction?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как сделать чтобы элемент `.content` помеченный в коде комментарием имел высоту своего родителя?

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.child:nth-child(1)>.content,
.child:nth-child(3)>.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <!-- у элемента ниже .content должна появится высота -->
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `heigth:100%;` Не?

Comment: @Дмытрык Неее..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Растянуть его flex-ом

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.child:nth-child(1)>.content,
.child:nth-child(3)>.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display:flex;
}
.child:nth-child(2) .content{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,black,white 5px)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <!-- у элемента ниже .content должна появится высота -->
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо.Оно самое.